# Why I can't assign result of std::from_chars to std::tie?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was thinking, that instead of `auto [x,y]` I can assign to `std::tie` made from existing variables but for some reason, it doesn't work. Can anyone tell why? I'm afraid that I don't understand compiler message. It seems to me that it tries to assign integer to the tuple (???)

```
#include <charconv>
#include <tuple>
int main()
{
    auto s = "123";
    unsigned int val;
    auto [p, err] = std::from_chars(s, s+3, val);       // this compiles
    std::tie(p,err) = std::from_chars(s, s+3, val);     // this doesn't compile
}
```

```
> c++ -std=c++17 foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:8:50: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::tuple<const char*&, std::errc&>’ and ‘std::__detail::__integer_from_chars_result_type<unsigned int>’ {aka ‘std::from_chars_result’})
     std::tie(p,err) = std::from_chars(s, s+3, val);     // this doesn't compile
                                                  ^
In file included from foo.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/8/tuple:1209:7: note: candidate: ‘std::tuple<_T1, _T2>& std::tuple<_T1, _T2>::operator=(const std::tuple<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const char*&; _T2 = std::errc&]’
       operator=(const tuple& __in)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/tuple:1209:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__detail::__integer_from_chars_result_type<unsigned int>’ {aka ‘std::from_chars_result’} to ‘const std::tuple<const char*&, std::errc&>&’
/usr/include/c++/8/tuple:1216:7: note: candidate: ‘std::tuple<_T1, _T2>& std::tuple<_T1, _T2>::operator=(std::tuple<_T1, _T2>&&) [with _T1 = const char*&; _T2 = std::errc&]’
       operator=(tuple&& __in)
```

And this example perfectly compiles:

```
int a, b, c;
std::tie(a, b, c) = std::make_tuple(2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: `std::tie` creates an object of type `std::tuple<...>` to which you cannot assign objects of arbitrary structures.

Comment: @otter but I see similar assignment in the example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie

Comment: Please pay attention to notes for this example: `std::tie may be used to unpack a std::pair because std::tuple has a converting assignment from pairs`

Comment: So what about this? It works!:
`int a, b, c;  std::tie(a, b, c) = std::make_tuple(2, 3, 4);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two different kind of constructs.

```
auto [p, err] = std::from_chars(s, s+3, val);       // this compiles
```

This is structured binding which can bind any structural element (Array, Structure, Tuple etc) to individual identifiers. See: [Structured Binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)

On the other hand this code:

```
std::tie(p,err) = std::from_chars(s, s+3, val);     // this doesn't compile
```

It is trying to assign a structure to a tuple for which, there is no implicit conversions possible. Only other tuple and pair objects can be assigned to tuples. See: [Tuple](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/)

Although you can override the assignment operator to convert the structure to a tuple and then your statement will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that from_chars returns struct and not a tuple. Strange that there is no solution for assigning existing variables similarly as with auto [].